# can i use 2 interstitial admob ad-units within same App?

Tags: admob, ads, interstitial

I am developing an app, were ther are **2 seperate Placements** for interstitials
( one in the app launch, i will deploy it for cross promotion House Ads )
second one inside the game, to earn money

==> can i use 2 seperate Ad Units for interstitials in one app ? 
so **in total i have 3 Ad -units** ( 1 for Banner and 2 for interstitals )  ?

Thank you

Comment: why don't you use RewardVideo Ad to earn money ?

Comment: reward video ( Appodeal .. heyzapp .. ) didn't work for me ! it's like admob is best choice in term of revenue

Comment: Admob start providing own RewardVideo Ad.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

According to the [Admob for Android Guide](https://developers.google.com/admob/android/quick-start), you can use two different interstitial adunits.

but I recommend you to use [Reward Video Ads](https://developers.google.com/admob/android/rewarded-video) for reward(earn money on gameplay).

Answer (score 1):

There is no problem using distinct interstitial adunits in the same app